# sending email using cakephp via smtp

Tags: php, email, cakephp, sendmail

i got a code working for sending basic email. but for smtp, i could not perfect this:

```
        function send(){

            $this->Email->smtpOptions = array(
                'port'=>'465', 
                'timeout'=>'30',
                'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
                'username'=>'csorila@gmail.com',
                'password'=>'mypassword',
           );

        $this->Email->delivery='smtp';

            $this->Email->send = 'debug';

            $this->Email->to = 'csorila17@gmail.com'; 
        $this->Email->subject = 'hurrah'; 
//        $this->Email->replyTo = 'noreply@example.com'; 
        $this->Email->from = 'Charmaine Khay Sorila<noreply@example.com>'; 
        //$this->Email->send('Here is the body of the email Chams Email Test');
        //Set the body of the mail as we send it. 
        //Note: the text can be an array, each element will appear as a 
        //seperate line in the message body. 

        if ( $this->Email->send() ) { 
            $this->Session->setFlash('Simple email sent'); 
        } else { 
            $this->Session->setFlash('Simple email not sent'); 
            $this->set('smtp_errors', $this->Email->smtpError);
        } 
        }

    }
```

i got this working without  $this->Email->delivery='smtp';, but when i added that line, no email can be sent at all  :(

Comment: You are using the debug option, try to remove it

Comment: same thing yossi..what actually happens is the page loads for a number of seconds then it won't send any email... :(

Comment: first: what is the error(s?) that you get?

Comment: when it was not sending, it doesnt display any errors provided that the debug mode is set to 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to actually send an email and instead want to test out the functionality, you can use the following delivery option:

```
Copy to Clipboard
$this->Email->delivery = 'debug';
```

Comment: there. i got it working but the thing is.. i checked if it is really the smtp that is being used to deliver my mail so i intentionally typed the password incorrectly but it still sent an email... >.<